# Ist „Schande“ in „ach du Schande!“ ein Euphemismus?

Tags: euphemism

Einfach so. Ich höre so oft  *„ach du Scheiße!“* und manchmal auch *„ach du Schande!“* in Kontexten, in denen man sich auf keinen Fall buchstäblich auf *Schande* als *Scham* beziehen würde.

Daher die Frage, ob *Schande* meint hier eigentlich *Scheiße*. (Ich meine, um diesen Ausdruck, den ich schon oft unbewust wiederhole, unter den Nicht-Kumpeln zu vermeiden.)

Comment: I hear that quite often as well. I consider it unpleasant to even read a fully written `Sch....`. However, this is MHO and the majority considers it *normal*.

Comment: @embert Tut mir Leid. Ich möchte aber hier auch nicht das Wort tabuisieren :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja, Schande bedeutet hier, dass man eigentlich Scheiße sagen würde, dies aber in der aktuellen Umgebung (Büro, ...) nicht möchte. Gesprochen wird dies auch oft so betont, als `Ach Du Sch....ande`.

Comment: vergleiche *Sch... eibenkleister* o.ä.

Comment: Im Gegensatz zu *Es ist wirklich eine Schande, dass ...*.

Answer (score 0):

Es handelt sich hier einfach um Verhüllung von Tabuwörtern. Kann sein, dass die Akademiker hierfür schon wieder einen Fachbegriff erfunden haben.